# JNI C function cannot be resolved in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a package named com.self.tryffmpeg.
There's a file MainActivity.java inside that package which declares two native functions from the C inside the JNI folder

```
static {

System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");  
System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-test-jni");   
}

    private native int createEngine();
private native String loadFile(String file, byte[] array);
  }
```

Inside the JNI folder, there's a C file which exports the functions needed by the MainActivity.java.

Inside the C , I exports the functions

```
NIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_self_tryffmpeg_MainActivity_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{

}


JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_self_tryffmpeg_MainActivity_loadFile(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jstring file,jbyteArray array) {
}
```

But the error is the functions of loadFile and createEngine cannot be resolved.  UnsatisfiedLinkError.  Did i do anything wrong with that.  I thought I export the functions correctly.

Comment: Post the exact logcat message showing the attempt to load the native library and the unsatisfied link error.

Comment: Judging by your C code, the `createEngine()` method should be declared __static__.

Comment: What @AlexCohn is saying is that the C function signature is not what would be produced by running javac and javah on the Java code you gave. You've probably changed the Java code and not updated the C code.

Comment: Another catch may be if the __package__ statement in __MainActivity.java__ does not comply with the _package_ declared in your __AndoroidManifest.xml__ file.

Comment: Alex, there's issue with package name.  I recreated the project and with consistent package name. It's resolved now.